# Read file from Azure Databricks DBFS REST 2.0 API

Tags: azure-databricks

I am working on an application to read and write files using Azure Databricks DBFS API 2.0. Reference Documentation for this API:
https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/dbfs.html#read

I am able to upload file (lets say 1.4MB file) by converting it into base64 then divided into 1MB chunks of data.

As the read length is limited to 1MB, I am iterating a loop to read data from offset `0` to `1000000` and `1000001` to `end of the file`. Now the first iteration of data, `0` - `1000000`, is valid and I can confirm from the original file which i used for upload.

But the second and later data iterations, the base64 data is completely different and not present in the original base64 file.

Following is my test code:
`Second iteration` - 0.4MB

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://********.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/read',
  data: {
    path: '/Test/backlit-beach-clouds-1684881.jpg',
    offset: 0,
    length: 1000000
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ****`
  }
}).then(({data}) => {
  if (data) {
    console.log('Success', data.bytes_read)
    fs.writeFile('./one.txt', data.data, function (err) {
      console.log('done', err)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('failed')
  }
})
```

`First iteration` - 1MB

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://********.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/read',
  data: {
    path: '/Test/backlit-beach-clouds-1684881.jpg',
    offset: 1000001,
    length: 1000000
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ****`
  }
}).then(({data}) => {
  if (data) {
    console.log('Success', data.bytes_read)
    fs.writeFile('./two.txt', data.data, function (err) {
      console.log('done', err)
    })
  } else {
    console.log('failed')
  }
})
```

Here, *** are replaced with relevant domain and tokens.

As you can see, the above test code samples will generate `one.txt` and `two.txt`. By using `cat one.txt two.txt > final.txt` I can get `final.txt` which I will use to decode original file.

As this is just a testing code, I haven't used any loops or better coding format. This is just to understand what went wrong.

I stuck with this for over 1 week now. I am referring other code samples written for python, but no help.

I am not trying to waste anyone's time. But please, someone help me to figure out what went wrong or any other standard procedure that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

I've run the same type of issue and solve it with an iterative extraction.

However in order to make it work I had to extract from 0 to 1000000 and 1000000 to end of the file.

Otherwise the base64 decoding part was not properly considering the beginning of the second slice.

I found that you don't need to add this extra byte from one slice to another.